# Python CSV read a single column as a list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have this code:

`type(i[0]) == 'str'`. How can I get it as a list? and later get `print(i[0][0]) == 'a'`

```
import csv
i = [['a', 'b'], 'c', 'd']
with open('a.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(i)

file.close()
with open('a.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for i in csv.reader(file, delimiter=';'):
        print(type(i[0]))
```

Comment: What is the contents of a.csv?

Comment: If you want to write a nested list, you might want to use `json` instead of `csv`.

Comment: Like @Samwise stated, you cannot write actual nested data. You can try as you have with `['a','b']` but the writer will always do the equivalent of `str(['a', 'b'])`, which is what you see in a.csv: `"['a', 'b']",c,d`.

Comment: content of each line of CSV is a list and two words which I wrote into a file. but I can not read the first list as a list. I get it as a string. and I do not know why.

Comment: so is there any solution without using JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is returning `str` instead of `list` because the csv writer will always do the equivalent of `str(['a','b'])`, which is  `"['a', 'b']",c,d`, so you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get the **list** from the **string list** like this for the first element-

```
import csv
import ast
i = [['a', 'b'], 'c', 'd']
with open('a.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(i)

file.close()
with open('a.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for i in csv.reader(file, delimiter=';'):
        i[0] = ast.literal_eval(i[0])
        print(type(i),type(i[0]), i[0][0])
```

Comment: It works very nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @Mhd glad it helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop. Like this:

example a.csv

```
hello, aloha, hola
bye, aloha, adios
```

python code:

```
import csv


col1 = []
with open('a.csv')  as file:
    r = csv.reader(file)
    for row in r:
        col1.append(row[0])

print(col1)  # => ['hello', 'bye']
```

Alternatively, you could also use a list comprehension:

```
import csv


col1 = []
with open('a.csv')  as file:
    r = csv.reader(file)
    col1 = [row[0] for row in r]

print(col1)  # => ['hello', 'bye']
```